# How to use "from Crypto.Cipher import AES" in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, kivy

I tried to complete an app for encrypting and decrypting by using AES, so I use `from Crypto.Cipher import AES` in my code. Then I write `kivy3 main.py` in terminal, but it printed out an ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'.

I tried to use`pip uninstall pycrypto`, but it printed out "Cannot uninstall 'pycrypto'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall."

My operating system is OSX 10.13.6

Comment: Try `pip3 install pycrypto`. `pip` may belong to Python 2. `pip -V` will show if it's Python 2 or Python 3.